# Mongodb - Aggregate by date

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to sum all fields price by date.

The mongodb schema is:

```
Flow({
    dateBuy: {type: Date},
    client: {type: String},
    price: {type: Number}
});
```

I am using the following query:

```
db.flow.aggregate([  
    {  
        "$group":{  
            "_id":{  
                "year":{  
                    "$year":"$dateBuy"
                },
                "month":{  
                    "$month":"$dateBuy"
                },
                "day":{  
                    "$dayOfMonth":"$dateBuy"
                }
            }
        },
        "value":{  
            "$sum":"$price"
        }
    }
])
```

However the following message is:

`2017-01-26T11:55:35.702-0200 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token >`

Someone would know how to solve this problem, I could not identify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try this `db.flow.aggregate([  
    {  
        "$group":{  
            "_id":{  
                "year":{  
                    "$year":"$dateBuy"
                },
                "month":{  
                    "$month":"$dateBuy"
                },
                "day":{  
                    "$dayOfMonth":"$dateBuy"
                }
            },
        "value":{  
            "$sum":"$price"
        }
    }
}
])`

Comment: Appeared`2017-01-26T12:24:52.555-0200 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token >`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed indentation - `value` should be on same level as `_id` field definition, inside $group operator

```
db.flow.aggregate([  
    {  
        "$group": {  
            "_id":{  
                "year":{ "$year":"$dateBuy" },
                "month":{ "$month":"$dateBuy" },
                "day":{ "$dayOfMonth":"$dateBuy" }
            }, 
            "value":{ "$sum":"$price" }
        }
        // your "value" is defined here, outside of $group operator
    }
])
```

Comment: I put it on the same level only the error continues `Unexpected token >`

Comment: @realcb21 there should be no errors, check all brackets carefully or just copy-paste answer

Comment: My error after using exactly the above code worked, thank you @Sergey Berezovskiy